# Very slow LAN connection because of the distance from the router

Tags: home-networking, lan

I have a 2Mbps Internet connection at home.  I also have two desktop computers.  One desktop computers is located in my room and the other is in the living room together with the router. The distance between the living room and my room is approximately 10 meters. I've read that if the LAN cable is longer from the router, the speed of the internet connection gets slower. I am not sure if that is true, but I'm encountering a slow internet connection when I'm using my computer in my room.  Also, I'm the only one using the internet during that time.

How can I resolve this?

When using the desktop in the living room I get the full speed of the Internet connection. But, when I use my computer in my room I only get 60% of the speed?

Comment: Actually a LAN cable, if properly shielded, can last up to 100 meters without degregation of the data rate, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I have several LAN cables at work that run close to the 100 meters.  They don't experience any degregation of speed.

Comment: What kind of "lan cable" are you using?  Is it in the wall or laying on the floor?  Who installed it?  Have you taken all precautions to avoid damaging the cable(s) (i.e. it's not kinked, not stepped on, radii are > 2")?  Are the cable(s) near sources of any electrical interference?

Comment: Hi everyone, I used a "regular" lan cable. I don't know anything about brands and others stuff about lan cable so i go to the nearest computer supply store and purchase meters of lan cable. I personally installed it. Actually, it's crawling in our ceiling going to the second floor then heading to my room. @sinni800, that was my question before, why is it in our office the internet connection never experience any degragation. Not until i've read that blog that says the longer the lan cable the internet connection gets affected. what might be the problem?

Comment: by the way, thank you for your response. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Perform some sanity checks: swap the PC from your room with the one next to the router.  OR obtain a *long* Cat5e cable to run from the router to your room (I have a 75 ft cable for such tests).  If either/both tests pass, then the installed cable run is suspect rather than connectors or the PC itself.  Cable is delicate and cannot be treated like rope: you must not pull too hard on it, kink it, pinch it, or bend it to a small radius.  A symptom of damaged cable is lowered speed.

Comment: Many Intel LAN cards comes with signal strength diagnotic feature. You'll have to install their full Proset driver and see if it can tell you anything wrong about the cable. If you don't have such an NIC, maybe you can borrow a friend's laptop or just buy one. It offers better performance anyways.

Comment: What operating system is that? With linux you could look with `ifconfig` (yes it's deprecated) for errors on the interface. I don't know how to do that with windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a switch between the router and computers. **

This definitely worked for me after re-crimping several times. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's true that if a cable is long the length can degrade its signal.

> CAT-5 is rated to 100M
>  CAT-5e is rated to 100M
>  CAT-6 and CAT6e is
>   rated to 550M or 1000M depending on the source

As you can see a CAT-5 cables shouldn't degrade until they hit lengths of 100 or more meters.

Perhaps there is something wrong with the cable you are currently using or the port on the router. Try switching LAN ports on each computer and see if the closer one gets a reduced speed. If this is the case use a different port. If not try a different cable.

Comment: Actually Cat-5e is rated to 100m too.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Fixed.

Comment: And also Cat6 and 6e: "When used for 10/100/1000BASE-T, the maximum allowed length of a Cat 6 cable is 100 meters or 328 feet."[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_6_cable)

Comment: by the way, thank you for your response. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Cable length is not an issue here. I'd say improper termination of the cable is the most probable reason for your issues, *if you installed the connectors yourself* (e.g. bought the cable in bulk and added the RG-45 connectors). [Learn how to terminate the cable](http://www.lanshack.com/make-cat5E.aspx) (install the connectors) properly, do not cut corners, do it really neatly and your cable should work OK.

Moreover, handle your LAN cable with respect: don't bend it too sharp, don't pull on it, don't staple it to your walls, etc.